# Putting tooltips programmatically on ListBox class

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have created an asp:listbox and in the cs file, I am trying to bind it to a datasource. However, I want to put in tooltips for each option so that when you hover over a multiple-listbox you will see the name of the item in both the listbox and the tooltip.

The following code is what I have tried (which obviously will not work), which will just put a big tooltip for the "select" html tag, instead of the "option" tags individually.

I think I need a loop, but I'm not sure how to add attributes to each element and the ASP documentation is no help. I bet it's an easy solution, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
  LBRangeOfUsers.DataSource = GetSource();
  LBRangeOfUsers.DataValueField = "id";
  LBRangeOfUsers.DataTextField = "desc";
  LBRangeOfUsers.Attributes.Add("title", "desc");
  LBRangeOfUsers.DataBind();
```

I tried this:

```
  int i = 0;
  foreach (ListItem li in LBRangeOfUsers.Items)
  {
      LBRangeOfUsers.Items[i].Attributes.Add("title", li.Value);
      i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me like this:

```
LBRangeOfUsers.DataSource = GetSource();
LBRangeOfUsers.DataBind();

foreach (ListItem item in LBRangeOfUsers.Items)
    item.Attributes["title"] = item.Value;
```

make sure the loop runs after the binding.

Comment: Yes that "after the binding" part works very well indeed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping through `LBRangeOfUsers.Items` and adding the Attribute for each [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for but it's not working. I put in my experiment above in my edit.

Comment: Well, of course you have to do it after you data bind.  Otherwise your list is empty.